# Palos y barajas, ¿Como repartir manos diferentes? POO

Tags: java, poo

Debo crear un programa que me genere Cartas (As - King) y también Palos, estas mismas serán repartidas a 3 usuarios (cada usuario tendrá 6 cartas) y debe mostrar una suma. El programa ya hace todo eso pero hay un problema que aun no puedo resolver, se supone que dos usuarios no pueden tener la misma carta, supongamos: Jugador 1 tiene Rey de corazones, entonces el Jugador 2 no puede tener esta misma carta.

En mi programa genera las cartas y palos pero en la mano de 2 o incluso de los 3 jugadores está la probabilidad de que me salga la misma carta, ¿Alguien podría darme alguna alternativa?

Anexo código:

1.- Con esta parte genero y reparto las cartas

```
    public void generarCartas(){

        revolver[i]=(int)(Math.random()*rangoCartas.length);  //genera los numeros aleatorios
            for(i=1; i<totalCartas; i++){
                revolver[i]=(int)(Math.random()*rangoCartas.length);
                for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
                    if(revolver[i]==revolver[j]){  //Esta condición evita que se repitan los numeros
                        i=i-1;
                    }
                }   
            }       
    }
    public void repartirCartas(){       
        for(int k=0; k<totalCartas; k++){ 
            String cartita = cartitas[revolver[k] %13 ];

            String palito = palitos[revolver[k] / 4 ];

            switch(revolver[k]){

            case 1:
                System.out.println("Tu carta numero " + (k+1) + " es el: " + cartita + " de " + palito );
                suma = suma + revolver[k];

            break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Tu carta numero " + (k+1) + " es el: " + cartita + " de " + palito );
                suma = suma + revolver[k] + 1;

                break;

            }

        }
        System.out.println("Total suma:" + (suma+1));
    }
```

2.- Con esta otra muestro la carta de cada jugador.

```
    MazoCartas jugador1;
    jugador1 = new MazoCartas();

    MazoCartas jugador2;
    jugador2 = new MazoCartas();

    MazoCartas jugador3;
    jugador3 = new MazoCartas();


    System.out.println("Mano jugador 1:");
    jugador1.generarCartas();
    jugador1.repartirCartas();

    System.out.println("Mano jugador 2:");
    jugador2.generarCartas();
    jugador2.repartirCartas();


    System.out.println("Mano jugador 3:");
    jugador3.generarCartas();
    jugador3.repartirCartas();
```

Comment: Creo que lo más normal sería reflejar lo que pasa en realidad: generar todas las cartas posibles (lo que sería la baraja) y de esta única baraja asignar cartas a las manos.

Comment: Que valor y que tipo tienen las variables `rangoCartas` y `totalCartas`, Ahora lo mejor que puedes hacer es crear una Baraja de cartas representada en un `ArrayList()` de `Cartas` ordenadas al azar, y cada jugador deberia tener una `Mano` de `Cartas` cada que entregas una carta a un jugador la remueves de la `Baraja` (`ArrayList().remove(0)`), de esta forma no deberia repetir carta en los jugadores.

Comment: Puedes también tener una lista con las cartas usadas y en uso e ignorar si estas están en la lista. Otra posibilidad es tener un Map y a cada carta le asignas un value true si esta en uso o false si no lo está, y vas repartiendo tirando de las false.

Answer (score 2):

La pregunta me causo mucho interes, el problema puede consistir en que se crea una baraja o mazo por cada jugador y esto puede generar coliciones de cartas entre los jugadores, la unica opción es tener un solo mazo para los tres jugadores, de los cuales se sacan cartas que se entregan a cada jugador pero las cuales se eliminan de la baraja, aca dejo una opción de solución con el fin de que evolucione de acuerdo a lo que cada usuario de la comunidad requiera.

Primero definimos las figuras y números de las cartas

```
public enum Figura {
  CORAZONES, DIAMANTES, PICAS, TREBOL
}

public enum Numero {
  AS, DOS, TRES, CUATRO, CINCO, SEIS, SIETE,  OCHO, NUEVE, J, Q, K   
}
```

Ahora definimos una carta

```
public class Carta {
  private final Figura figura;
  private final Numero numero;
  public Carta(Figura f, Numero n){
    this.figura = f;
    this.numero = n;
  }
  public Figura getFigura() {
    return figura;
  }
  public Numero getNumero() {
    return numero;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return this.numero.toString() + "-" + this.figura.toString();
  }
}
```

Ahora definimos una Baraja o mazo

```
public class Baraja {
  private List<Carta> baraja;
  public Baraja(){
    this.construir();
  }
  private void construir(){
    this.baraja = new ArrayList();
    for(Figura f : Figura.values()){
      for(Numero n : Numero.values()){
        this.baraja.add(new Carta(f, n));
      }
    }
  }
  public void mezclar(byte cantidad){
    int nVeces = cantidad * this.baraja.size();
    Random random = new Random();
    int index = 0;
    Carta carta;
    for(int i = 0; i < nVeces; i++){
      index = random.nextInt(this.baraja.size());
      carta = this.baraja.remove(index);
      index = random.nextInt(this.baraja.size());
      this.baraja.add(index, carta);
    }
  }
  public int getNumeroCartas(){
    return this.baraja.size();
  }
  public Carta getCarta(){
    return this.baraja.remove(0);
  }
  public boolean estaVacia(){
    return this.baraja.isEmpty();
  }
  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return this.baraja.toString();
  }
}
```

En todo juego de cartas hay un dealer quien administra la baraja

```
public class Dealer {
  private Baraja baraja;
  public Dealer(Baraja baraja){
    this.baraja = baraja;
  }
  public void mezclarBaraja(byte cantidad){
    this.baraja.mezclar(cantidad);
  }
  public Carta entregarCarta(){
    return this.baraja.getCarta();
  }
  public String mostrarBaraja(){
    return this.baraja.toString();
  }
  public int getNumeroCartas(){
    return this.baraja.getNumeroCartas();
  }
}
```

Tambien hay jugadores

```
public class Jugador {
  private List<Carta> mano;
  private String nombre;
  public Jugador(String nombre){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.mano = new ArrayList();
  }
  public void adicionarCarta(Carta carta){
    this.mano.add(carta);
  }
  public Carta botarCarta(int index){
    return this.mano.remove(index);
  }
  @Override
  public String toString(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Jugador: ")
      .append(this.nombre)
      .append("\n").append(this.mano.toString());
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Y por último, tenemos el juego

```
public class Juego {
  private List<Jugador> jugadores;
  private Dealer dealer;
  public Juego(){
    this.dealer = new Dealer(new Baraja());
    this.dealer.mezclarBaraja((byte)15);
    this.jugadores = new ArrayList();
  }
  public void addJugador(Jugador jugador){
    this.jugadores.add(jugador);
  }
  public void repartirCartas(byte numeroCartas){
    for(Jugador j : this.jugadores){
      for(byte i = 0; i < numeroCartas; i++){
        j.adicionarCarta(this.dealer.entregarCarta());
      } 
    }
  }
  public String mostrarBaraja(){
    return this.dealer.mostrarBaraja();
  }
  public int getNumeroCartasDealer(){
    return this.dealer.getNumeroCartas();
  }
  public List<Jugador> getJugadores(){
    return this.jugadores;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Juego juego = new Juego();
    System.out.println("Baraja Inicial de :" + juego.getNumeroCartasDealer() + " cartas." );
    System.out.println(juego.mostrarBaraja());
    juego.addJugador(new Jugador("Jugador-1"));
    juego.addJugador(new Jugador("Jugador-2"));
    juego.addJugador(new Jugador("Jugador-3"));
    juego.repartirCartas((byte)6);
    System.out.println("\n----- Cartas por Jugador ------\n");
    for(Jugador j : juego.getJugadores()){
      System.out.println(j.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Baraja Final de :" + juego.getNumeroCartasDealer() + " cartas." );
    System.out.println(juego.mostrarBaraja());
  }
}
```

y aca un ejemplo de la salida, donde vemos la baraja inicial mezclada, y posteriormente la cartas de cada jugador y las cartas con las que quedo el dealer donde podemos observar que no hay coliciones de cartas

```
Baraja Inicial de :48 cartas.
[SEIS-DIAMANTES, TRES-DIAMANTES, CUATRO-TREBOL, Q-TREBOL, J-TREBOL, CUATRO-CORAZONES, J-DIAMANTES, OCHO-TREBOL, OCHO-DIAMANTES, Q-PICAS, J-CORAZONES, CINCO-TREBOL, SEIS-TREBOL, SIETE-CORAZONES, TRES-CORAZONES, K-DIAMANTES, NUEVE-TREBOL, AS-PICAS, SIETE-DIAMANTES, Q-CORAZONES, NUEVE-DIAMANTES, SIETE-TREBOL, TRES-PICAS, CUATRO-PICAS, AS-CORAZONES, AS-DIAMANTES, AS-TREBOL, DOS-CORAZONES, DOS-TREBOL, TRES-TREBOL, CINCO-PICAS, Q-DIAMANTES, J-PICAS, CUATRO-DIAMANTES, SIETE-PICAS, NUEVE-PICAS, CINCO-DIAMANTES, SEIS-PICAS, OCHO-CORAZONES, DOS-PICAS, K-TREBOL, K-PICAS, CINCO-CORAZONES, DOS-DIAMANTES, SEIS-CORAZONES, OCHO-PICAS, NUEVE-CORAZONES, K-CORAZONES]
----- Cartas por Jugador ------
Jugador: Jugador-1
[SEIS-DIAMANTES, TRES-DIAMANTES, CUATRO-TREBOL, Q-TREBOL, J-TREBOL, CUATRO-CORAZONES]
Jugador: Jugador-2
[J-DIAMANTES, OCHO-TREBOL, OCHO-DIAMANTES, Q-PICAS, J-CORAZONES, CINCO-TREBOL]
Jugador: Jugador-3
[SEIS-TREBOL, SIETE-CORAZONES, TRES-CORAZONES, K-DIAMANTES, NUEVE-TREBOL, AS-PICAS]
Baraja Final de :30 cartas.
[SIETE-DIAMANTES, Q-CORAZONES, NUEVE-DIAMANTES, SIETE-TREBOL, TRES-PICAS, CUATRO-PICAS, AS-CORAZONES, AS-DIAMANTES, AS-TREBOL, DOS-CORAZONES, DOS-TREBOL, TRES-TREBOL, CINCO-PICAS, Q-DIAMANTES, J-PICAS, CUATRO-DIAMANTES, SIETE-PICAS, NUEVE-PICAS, CINCO-DIAMANTES, SEIS-PICAS, OCHO-CORAZONES, DOS-PICAS, K-TREBOL, K-PICAS, CINCO-CORAZONES, DOS-DIAMANTES, SEIS-CORAZONES, OCHO-PICAS, NUEVE-CORAZONES, K-CORAZONES]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Es importante tener encuenta que este código es para mostrar como manejar o administrar una sola baraja para varios jugadores, y no pretende ser el super juego de cartas, esa parte queda a discreción de cada usuario.