# agregar cartas a una pila que representa el mazo de cartas

Tags: java

No se hacer este método:

> public boolean añadirCarta(Carta carta) Añade la carta recibida como argumento a la parte superior de la pila que representa el mazo de cartas. Parameters: carta - La carta que se añade en la cima del mazo. Returns: true si se pudo añadir o false si no se pudo añadir.

Me da siempre el error de: no se puede añadir una carta cuando aun es posible hacerlo.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
public class MazoDeCartas {

    private Carta mazoCartas[];

    public MazoDeCartas(int numeroMaximoDeCartas){

        mazoCartas=new Carta[numeroMaximoDeCartas];

    }

    public boolean anadirCarta(Carta carta){
        for(int i = 0; i < mazoCartas.length; i++){
            if(mazoCartas[i] == null){
                mazoCartas[i] = carta;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    public Carta extraerCarta(){
         Carta cartaExt=null;
         boolean encontrar=false;
         for(int i=mazoCartas.length-1;i>=0;i--){
             if(mazoCartas[i]!=null && (!encontrar)){
                 cartaExt=mazoCartas[i];
                 mazoCartas[i]=null;
                 encontrar=true;
             }
         }
        return cartaExt;

    }
    public void barajar(){

    }
}
```

El problema esta en el método anadirCarta.

Comment: no se puede añadir una carta no es un error, cual es el error que recibis? y en linea lo tira? y que esperas que haga exactamente?

Comment: Nunca había visto un constructor así: `mazoCartas=new Carta[numeroMaximoDeCartas];` usando `[]`  en vez de `()`. ¿Ese código compila?

Comment: En el test que tiene que pasar para considerarlo correcto, me dice que: Se añade una carta cuando no debe ser posible hacerlo.

Comment: Si, si deja compilar.

Comment: aja.. y como es el test?? falta mucha informacion para poder ayudarte.. sobre todo la definicion del test

Comment: @A.Cedano es java, el constructor del array es correcto.

Comment: Yo quisiera ver la clase `Carta`... la verdad que me sorprende  esa línea: `mazoCartas=new Carta[numeroMaximoDeCartas];`

Comment: La clase carta esta bien. Solo quiero saber como hacer el método añadirCarta.

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque sólo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855)

Comment: @A.Cedano es java, esta bien eso, si no mira [aca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java)

Comment: @iHack anexa el error que indica en tu pregunta como te indica java

Comment: En ese caso la variable private debería estar declarada así: **`private Carta [] mazoCartas;`** Es un array de objetos de esa clase que quieres crear, ¿no?

Comment: Si, pero el tema es que para de añadir cartas cuando aun puede

Comment: Yo no veo desde dónde llamas al método `anadirCarta`

Comment: Revise la respuesta a esta entrada y valide que funcionalidad le puede servir https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108117/palos-y-barajas-como-repartir-manos-diferentes-poo/108204#108204

Answer (score 0):

```
package pruebas;

public class MazoDeCartas {

    private static Carta[] mazoCartas;
    private int numeroMaximoDeCartas;
    private static int cartasEnMazo;

    public MazoDeCartas( int nMaximoDeCartas ) {
        System.out.println( "Creando mazo de " + nMaximoDeCartas + " cartas..." );

        MazoDeCartas.mazoCartas = new Carta[ nMaximoDeCartas ];
        this.numeroMaximoDeCartas = nMaximoDeCartas;


        //Reinicia el mazo cada vez que se crea una nueva instancia
        MazoDeCartas.cartasEnMazo = 0;
    }

    public boolean anadirCarta( Carta carta ) {
        System.out.println( "Cartas en el mazo: " + cartasEnMazo );

        if( cartasEnMazo < this.numeroMaximoDeCartas ) {
            System.out.println( "Añadiendo carta: " + carta.getName( ));

            MazoDeCartas.mazoCartas[ cartasEnMazo ] = carta;
            MazoDeCartas.cartasEnMazo++;

            return true;
        }


        return false;
    }

} //class

class Carta {

    private String name = null;

    public Carta( String name ) {

        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return this.name;
    }
} //class
```

He creado la clase Carta sólo con la propiedad "name", lo mínimo necesario para hacerlo funcionar. He añadido trazas para que puedas ver por donde va el programa. A continuación la clase de test:

```
package pruebas;

/**
 *
 * @author orici
 */
public class TestMazoDeCartas {

    public static void main( String[] args ){
        System.out.println( "TestMazoDeCartas" );

        MazoDeCartas mdc = new MazoDeCartas( 3 );

        if ( mdc.anadirCarta( new Carta( "a" )))
            System.out.println( "Añadida primera carta" );

        if ( mdc.anadirCarta( new Carta( "b" )))
            System.out.println( "Añadida segunda carta" );

        if ( mdc.anadirCarta( new Carta( "c" )))
            System.out.println( "Añadida tercera carta" );

        if ( mdc.anadirCarta( new Carta( "d" )))
            System.out.println( "Añadida cuarta carta" );
    }

} //class
```

Está es la salida a la ejecución del test:

```
run:
TestMazoDeCartas
Creando mazo de 3 cartas...
Cartas en el mazo: 0
Añadiendo carta: a
Añadida primera carta
Cartas en el mazo: 1
Añadiendo carta: b
Añadida segunda carta
Cartas en el mazo: 2
Añadiendo carta: c
Añadida tercera carta
Cartas en el mazo: 3
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Necesitabas algunas propiedades estáticas y un condicional el lugar de un bucle, también creo que deberías comprobar que la carta que vas a añadir no este ya en el mazo.

Saludos.

Comment: me encataria saber como adivinaste que queria OP, pq habla de agregar cartas a una pila (que no tiene) y no se entiende pq le da error.

Comment: Creo que esta claro que la pila de cartas es el array declarado en: private static Carta[] mazoCartas;

Comment: Lo que pasa es q lo que escribio habla de la pila que representa el mazo de cartas. No del mazo de cartas a secas, pero puede ser un problema de semantica solamente.

Comment: No se decirte, cogí lo que entendí de lo que puso y rellene los huecos con lo que yo haría en una situación similar. A ver si el usuario que pregunto se pronuncia...