# ¿Que significa: "Exportando tipos no públicos a partir de una api pública"?

Tags: java, netbeans

Me aparece un *warning* en ***Netbeans*** con el mensaje del título.
Cuando vas a "Sugerencias" a ver la explicación aparece ésto:

> Comprueba que devuelve tipos y tipos de parámetros de todos los
>   métodos públicos y que todos los tipos de campos públicos están
>   públicamente disponibles desde otros paquetes. Tener tipos o paquetes
>   privados en una API no tiene utilidad.
>
> Refactoring: No associated refactoring.

Supongo que es por la traducción pero no se de que habla... ¿Alguien puede explicarlo?

***PD:*** el código es el de ésta pregunta: [Como hacer este método](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/113993). El mensaje aparece en la firma del método: **anadirCarta()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás haciendo referencia a la firma siguiente:

```
public boolean anadirCarta(Carta carta){
```

El mensaje te está avisando de que si vas a exponer un método de forma pública, entonces todos los elementos en la firma deben ser públicos también.

En este caso, parece que `Carta` no es una clase pública. Y eso es un problema, porque, aunque alguien tenga acceso al método público `anadirCarta`, no tendrá acceso a `Carta`, de modo que nunca podrá pasarle los parámetros que necesita para poder ejecutar el método con éxito.

Comment: Buena. Habría que hacer un diccionario de explicaciones de los warnings del **Netbeans**, que son temas importante de Java pero raramente se entienden si no tienes cierta experiencia.