# ¿Afecta al SEO que los enlaces incluyan una ID de referencia?

Tags: seo, pretty-urls

Las URLs, como las de éste mismo sitio, tienen un identificador para cada página. Por ejemplo usar la siguiente URL: `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114535/que-significa-exportando-tipos-no-públicos-a-partir-de-una-api-pública`
es igual que usar ésta: `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114535` para acceder a la pregunta. Entiendo que a nivel de SEO hay que usar la primera, pero incluir una ID como **114535** ¿tiene algún efecto en el SEO?

Comment: Hola @Orici, no se mucho de SEO, pero lo que se es que ambas URLs tienen un formato "amigable", las URLs no "amigables" son las de tipo "http://sitio.dominio?tema=12345", te dejo un enlace con algo de información: https://moz.com/learn/seo/url , puedes encontrar mucho hacerca de SEO en Google.

Comment: Yo creo que la parte principal del SEO es la parte de la URL que la hace amigable. El ID entiendo que es el identificador para la relación en la base de datos a modo de puntero.

En resumidas cuentas el ID dudo mucho que sirva para SEO, la gente en un buscador no busca por la ID, busca por palabras :)

Comment: @Eduardorq yo entiendo que no mejora el SEO, la pregunta va más enfocada hacia lo contrario

Answer (score 0):

No, no afecta al seo por que se declara una url canonica.

la url canonica ayuda a los buscadores a identificar cual es la version correcta de la url, excluyendo parametros y otras cosas.